# Poltergeist page.driver.resize(width, height) and page.driver.scroll_to(left, top) are doing nothing

Tags: phantomjs, poltergeist

I'm using poltergiest and phantomjs for my integration tests and I need to test behavior for a user scrolling down the page and adjusting the browser window. I've used both `page.driver.resize(width, height)` and `page.driver.scroll_to(left, top)`. I've taken screenshots before and after the method is called, and nothing seems to happen. The method is called successfully, but has no effect on the page. Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one for resizing:

```
page.driver.resize_window(width, height)
```